# Setting GPS waypoints in tum_simulator

Tags: ros, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the following tutorial: https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator I've been able to simulate flying an ardrone in gazebo. I can receive gps coordinates/ latitude from the /fix rostopic. However, I can't see a way to set gps-waypoints?

I've tried using the [gps-waypoint branch of ardrone_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/tree/gps-waypoint) and enabling nav_data_gps in a number of places in the launch files but nothing seems to work.

Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227659/setting-gps-waypoints-in-tum_simulator/) by [djdmorrison](https://answers.ros.org/users/26082/djdmorrison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Trinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/27573/trinto/) on 2016-07-22**:
did u solve that autopilot problem? if so, could u tell me how please?

**Comment by [djdmorrison](https://answers.ros.org/users/26082/djdmorrison/) on 2016-07-22**:
I didn't unfortunately. I ended up using the x and y coordinates of the drone as if they were lat-lng coordinates and manually moving towards points by rotating towards the correct direction and moving forward manually.

**Comment by [djdmorrison](https://answers.ros.org/users/26082/djdmorrison/) on 2016-07-22**:
This was only really a solution as I was flying in straight lines and rotating at right angles however. I'm sure you could work out more complex flight paths using a bit of maths though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've done precisely that a few months ago. I managed to create a separate controller that publishes appropriate velocity commands to the topic and reads the position. So you would have to create a closed loop. As far as I know there are no libraries for autonomous flight compatible with tum_simulator.

---

Originally posted by [Pickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/24593/pickman/) with karma: 31 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0